# Python 3 extract html data

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have been trying to extract data from a html page but have been failing so far. Given the following html page how do I extract 2019 and 0.7 from the page using python 3? It would be helpful if the provided solution is also able to be expanded to extract other data like the 0.2 and 0.5 from the same row.

```
    <div class="row" style='margin: 0'>
        <div class="side-menu">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="brand-wrapper">
                        <!-- Hamburger -->
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                                class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                                class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Brand -->
                        <div class="brand-name-wrapper">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                                Dividends.sg </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Main Menu -->
                <div class="side-menu-container">
                    <ul id="w1" class="nav navbar-nav menu"><li><a href="/user/login"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></i> Login</a></li>
<li><a href="/"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Quick Search</a></li>
<li><a href="/stocks/1"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i> My Stocks</a></li>
<li><a href="/note/index"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> My Notes</a></li>
<li><a href="/rank/blue"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up'></i> Dividends Ranking</a></li>
<li><a href="/dividend/coming"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'></i> Coming Dividends</a></li>
<li><a href="/ann/insider"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-bell'></i> Announcements</a></li>
<li><a href="/ann/buyback"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-usd'></i> Recent Buy Backs</a></li>
<li><a href="https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/world-indices" target="_blank"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot'></i> World indices</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.ggg.sg" target="_blank"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></i> Room for rent</a></li></ul>               </div>
            </nav>

        </div>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class='side-body'>

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-8' style='position: relative'>
        <div style='position: static'>
            <!-- ads0 start --><div id="ads0" class="adsDiv" style="margin-bottom:5px;max-height:200px">        <ins class="adsbygoogle" data-ad-slot="3811773152" data-ad-client="ca-pub-5098302407872782" style='display:block;' data-ad-format='auto'></ins>
        <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></div><!-- ads0 end -->      </div>


<div style='margin: 20px 0'>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www2.sgx.com/securities/equities/V03" target="_blank">SGX</a>  <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=SGX:V03" target="_blank">Google</a> <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=V03.SI" target="_blank">Yahoo</a> <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.google.com.sg/search?tbm=nws&amp;q=Venture" target="_blank">News</a></div>
<h4 style='line-height: 30px'>
    VENTURE CORPORATION LIMITED (V03)   <span class='label label-default'>SGD 15.25 </span> <br />
</h4>

<div class='bottom-10 btn-list'>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="/dividend/add-stock?company_id=967"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty'></i> Portfolio</a><a class="btn btn-success" href="/dividend/add-watch?company_id=967"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty'></i> Watchlist</a></div>

<ul id="w0" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom:10px;"><li class="active"><a href="/view/V03"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-usd'></i> Dividends</a></li>
<li><a href="/announcement/V03"><i class='fa fa-bullhorn'></i> Announces</a></li>
<li><a href="/notes/V03"><i class='fa fa-sticky-note-o'></i> Notes</a></li></ul>

Dividend Yield(TTM) =
4.59%


<p style='color: orange'>
    If you find any of the dividend record is wrong or duplicated, please <a
        href='https://service.orgs.live/email?lang=en'><u>contact me.</u></a>
</p>

<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
    <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
                <th>Yield</th>
        <th>Total</th>

                <th>Amount</th>

        <th>Ex Date</th>

                <th class='hidden-xs'>Pay Date</th>
                <th class='visible-lg visible-md'>Particulars</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2020</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2020-06-08</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2020-06-16        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/380216" target="_blank">Rate: SGD 0.5  Per Security</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2019</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>4.59%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.7</td>               <td>SGD0.2      </td>

        <td>2019-09-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2019-09-19        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/268898" target="_blank">Rate: SGD 0.2  Per Security</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2019-05-10</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2019-05-22        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/114981" target="_blank">Rate: SGD 0.5  Per Security</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2018</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>5.25%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.8</td>               <td>SGD0.2      </td>

        <td>2018-09-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2018-09-19        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/33487" target="_blank">SGD 0.2 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.6      </td>

        <td>2018-05-17</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2018-05-31        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/32445" target="_blank">SGD 0.6 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2017</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2017-05-15</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2017-05-25        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/29472" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2016</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2016-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2016-05-18        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/26364" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2015</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2015-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2015-05-20        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/23144" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2014</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2014-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2014-05-19        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/20093" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2013</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2013-05-02</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2013-05-15        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/17058" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2012</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.61%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.55</td>              <td>SGD0.55     </td>

        <td>2012-05-03</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2012-05-18        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/15808" target="_blank">SGD 0.55 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2011</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.61%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.55</td>              <td>SGD0.55     </td>

        <td>2011-05-11</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2011-05-26        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/14742" target="_blank">SGD 0.55 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2010</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2010-05-06</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2010-05-20        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/13118" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2009</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2009-04-30</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2009-05-26        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/12089" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>2008</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.5      </td>

        <td>2008-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2008-05-20        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/11072" target="_blank">SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='3' style='vertical-align:middle'>2007</td><td rowspan='3' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.80%</td><td rowspan='3' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.58</td>              <td>SGD0.08     </td>

        <td>2007-08-22</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2007-09-05        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/10340" target="_blank">SGD 0.08 LESS TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.25     </td>

        <td>2007-05-04</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2007-05-22        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/9926" target="_blank">SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.25     </td>

        <td>2007-05-04</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2007-05-22        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/9925" target="_blank">SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2006</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.25     </td>

        <td>2006-05-03</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2006-05-18        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/8864" target="_blank">SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.25     </td>

        <td>2006-05-03</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2006-05-18        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/8863" target="_blank">SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2005</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>3.28%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.5</td>               <td>SGD0.25     </td>

        <td>2005-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2005-05-20        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/8010" target="_blank">SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.25     </td>

        <td>2005-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2005-05-20        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/8009" target="_blank">SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2004</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>1.23%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.188</td>             <td>SGD0.125        </td>

        <td>2004-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2004-05-19        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/7211" target="_blank">SGD 0.125 LESS TAX</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.0625       </td>

        <td>2004-05-05</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2004-05-19        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/7210" target="_blank">SGD 0.0625 TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2003</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.15     </td>

        <td>2003-05-29</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2003-06-16        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/6580" target="_blank">15% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.15     </td>

        <td>2003-05-29</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2003-06-16        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/6579" target="_blank">15% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2002</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.1      </td>

        <td>2002-05-23</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2002-06-11        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/5848" target="_blank">10% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.1      </td>

        <td>2002-05-23</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2002-06-11        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/5847" target="_blank">10% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2001</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.1      </td>

        <td>2001-06-14</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2001-06-29        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/5354" target="_blank">10% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.1      </td>

        <td>2001-06-14</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2001-06-29        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/5353" target="_blank">10% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2000</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.08     </td>

        <td>2000-06-27</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2000-07-12        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/4718" target="_blank">8% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.08     </td>

        <td>2000-06-27</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>2000-07-12        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/4717" target="_blank">8% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>1999</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.08     </td>

        <td>1999-06-23</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1999-07-14        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/4158" target="_blank">8% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.08     </td>

        <td>1999-06-23</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1999-07-14        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/4157" target="_blank">8% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>1998</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.04     </td>

        <td>1998-06-24</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1998-07-13        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/3629" target="_blank">4% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.04     </td>

        <td>1998-06-24</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1998-07-13        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/3628" target="_blank">4% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle'>1997</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='1' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>SGD0.08     </td>

        <td>1997-06-25</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1997-07-16        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/2807" target="_blank">INC BONUS DIV 8% TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan='5' style='vertical-align:middle'>1996</td><td rowspan='5' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>0.00%</td><td rowspan='5' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0</td>             <td>-       </td>

        <td>1996-06-24</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>-     </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/13747" target="_blank">OFFER OF 1 FOR 2 @ SGD 1.6</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>-       </td>

        <td>1996-06-24</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>-     </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/2802" target="_blank">OFFER OF 1 FOR 1</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>-       </td>

        <td>1996-06-11</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1996-07-03        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/6581" target="_blank">BONUS DIV (SGD) 0.5 CENTS TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.005        </td>

        <td>1996-06-11</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1996-07-03        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/2808" target="_blank">BONUS DIV (S$) 0.5 CENTS TAX EXEMPTED</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
                        <td>SGD0.01     </td>

        <td>1996-06-11</td>

                <td class='hidden-xs'>1996-07-03        </td>

        <td class='visible-lg visible-md'><a href="https://links.sgx.com/1.0.0/corporate-actions/2806" target="_blank">(SGD) 1 CENTS TAX EXEMPT</a></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: Is there a specific structure of the page you’re trying to extract? It seems what you want to do is to parse the HTML structure itself.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I guess the structure I am trying to extract is <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>

Comment: Which 0.7? Which 2019? i.e. what is the more generic pattern you’re trying to match? (Descriptively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to read this table will be using `pandas`.

For example (if `page.html` is your page from the question):

```
import pandas as pd

with open('page.html', 'r') as f_in:
    df = pd.read_html(f_in)[0]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Year  Yield      Total     Amount     Ex Date    Pay Date                            Particulars
0   2020.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2020-06-08  2020-06-16             Rate: SGD 0.5 Per Security
1   2019.0  4.59%    SGD 0.7     SGD0.2  2019-09-05  2019-09-19             Rate: SGD 0.2 Per Security
2   2019.0  4.59%    SGD 0.7     SGD0.5  2019-05-10  2019-05-22             Rate: SGD 0.5 Per Security
3   2018.0  5.25%    SGD 0.8     SGD0.2  2018-09-05  2018-09-19                   SGD 0.2 ONE-TIER TAX
4   2018.0  5.25%    SGD 0.8     SGD0.6  2018-05-17  2018-05-31                   SGD 0.6 ONE-TIER TAX
5   2017.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2017-05-15  2017-05-25                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
6   2016.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2016-05-05  2016-05-18                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
7   2015.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2015-05-05  2015-05-20                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
8   2014.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2014-05-05  2014-05-19                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
9   2013.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2013-05-02  2013-05-15                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
10  2012.0  3.61%   SGD 0.55    SGD0.55  2012-05-03  2012-05-18                  SGD 0.55 ONE-TIER TAX
11  2011.0  3.61%   SGD 0.55    SGD0.55  2011-05-11  2011-05-26                  SGD 0.55 ONE-TIER TAX
12  2010.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2010-05-06  2010-05-20                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
13  2009.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2009-04-30  2009-05-26                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
14  2008.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5     SGD0.5  2008-05-05  2008-05-20                   SGD 0.5 ONE-TIER TAX
15  2007.0  3.80%   SGD 0.58    SGD0.08  2007-08-22  2007-09-05                      SGD 0.08 LESS TAX
16  2007.0  3.80%   SGD 0.58    SGD0.25  2007-05-04  2007-05-22                    SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT
17  2007.0  3.80%   SGD 0.58    SGD0.25  2007-05-04  2007-05-22                    SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT
18  2006.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5    SGD0.25  2006-05-03  2006-05-18                    SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT
19  2006.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5    SGD0.25  2006-05-03  2006-05-18                    SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT
20  2005.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5    SGD0.25  2005-05-05  2005-05-20                    SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT
21  2005.0  3.28%    SGD 0.5    SGD0.25  2005-05-05  2005-05-20                    SGD 0.25 TAX EXEMPT
22  2004.0  1.23%  SGD 0.188   SGD0.125  2004-05-05  2004-05-19                     SGD 0.125 LESS TAX
23  2004.0  1.23%  SGD 0.188  SGD0.0625  2004-05-05  2004-05-19                  SGD 0.0625 TAX EXEMPT
24  2003.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.15  2003-05-29  2003-06-16                         15% TAX EXEMPT
25  2003.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.15  2003-05-29  2003-06-16                         15% TAX EXEMPT
26  2002.0  0.00%      SGD 0     SGD0.1  2002-05-23  2002-06-11                         10% TAX EXEMPT
27  2002.0  0.00%      SGD 0     SGD0.1  2002-05-23  2002-06-11                         10% TAX EXEMPT
28  2001.0  0.00%      SGD 0     SGD0.1  2001-06-14  2001-06-29                         10% TAX EXEMPT
29  2001.0  0.00%      SGD 0     SGD0.1  2001-06-14  2001-06-29                         10% TAX EXEMPT
30  2000.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.08  2000-06-27  2000-07-12                          8% TAX EXEMPT
31  2000.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.08  2000-06-27  2000-07-12                          8% TAX EXEMPT
32  1999.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.08  1999-06-23  1999-07-14                          8% TAX EXEMPT
33  1999.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.08  1999-06-23  1999-07-14                          8% TAX EXEMPT
34  1998.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.04  1998-06-24  1998-07-13                          4% TAX EXEMPT
35  1998.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.04  1998-06-24  1998-07-13                          4% TAX EXEMPT
36  1997.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.08  1997-06-25  1997-07-16            INC BONUS DIV 8% TAX EXEMPT
37  1996.0  0.00%      SGD 0          -  1996-06-24           -             OFFER OF 1 FOR 2 @ SGD 1.6
38  1996.0  0.00%      SGD 0          -  1996-06-24           -                       OFFER OF 1 FOR 1
39  1996.0  0.00%      SGD 0          -  1996-06-11  1996-07-03   BONUS DIV (SGD) 0.5 CENTS TAX EXEMPT
40  1996.0  0.00%      SGD 0   SGD0.005  1996-06-11  1996-07-03  BONUS DIV (S$) 0.5 CENTS TAX EXEMPTED
41  1996.0  0.00%      SGD 0    SGD0.01  1996-06-11  1996-07-03               (SGD) 1 CENTS TAX EXEMPT
42     NaN    NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN         NaN                                    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand how this works though. What does     df = pd.read_html(f_in)[0] do?

Comment: @user3702643 `df = pd.read_html(f_in)[0]` means to read every `<table>` found in file `f_in`, then select first one (the `[0]` part). More here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: so i can use pandas any time there is a table in the html page?

Comment: @user3702643 Generally yes. There are exceptions though: the page is using JavasScript to load the data for example.